# How do I write a Windows 10 universal class library that references native code?

Tags: winapi, native-code, win-universal-app

I have a C# class library that references and wraps Win32 native methods.  But I can't seem to port this code over to a newer "universal" C# class library.  What do I need to do in order to properly marshal these native methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 Universal Applications run under the [Windows Runtime API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime), a new "native" API for Windows. Applications using this API run in a sandbox which limits their access to devices and operating system services. While Win32 APIs can be accessed like normal, for example using P/Invoke in the case of C# code, [the sandbox only permits the use of certain API functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx):

> Windows Runtime apps can use a subset of the Win32 and COM APIs. This
>   subset of APIs was chosen to support key scenarios for Windows Runtime
>   apps that were not already covered by the Windows Runtime, HTML/CSS,
>   or other supported languages or standards. The Windows App
>   Certification Kit ensures that your app uses only this subset of the
>   Win32 and COM API. In a native app, you can call these APIs directly.
>   In a managed app, you can call them via a Windows Runtime Component,
>   or via P/Invoke.
>
> ...
>
> The documentation for each programming element in the API indicates
>   whether it can be used in a Windows Runtime app. See the "Applies to"
>   line at the top of the page.

So for example [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx) works with Windows Runtime, but [GetNamedPipeInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365445.aspx) doesn't.

If the Win32 API you want to use isn't one of the ones supported by Windows Runtime, I believe your only option is to have your class library target traditional desktop apps.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  That was extremely helpful.  As it turns out, I am trying to do p/invoke on "static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(...)".  The SafeFileHandle doesn't exist in the System.Runtime.InteropServices of a Universal Application class library (only SafeHandle exists).  So if I understand you correctly, I won't be able to port this to a universal app class library, and I must stick to a traditional desktop app.

Comment: @tambui I'm guessing you're using CreateFile to access a device, not a regular file. In that case unless you can find some sort of API for the device that works in sandbox, you're limited to desktop apps.

Comment: If you just want to open regular files, and those files are within your app's install folder or local storage, you can P/Invoke to `CreateFile2` instead,

Comment: Ross, you are correct in understanding my usage.  Thanks again for the information.